# Simultaneous diagonalization in infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Assume that we have two commuting matrices $A$ and $B$. I have already proved that they are simultaneously diagonalizable, even with degenerate spectrums. How do I extend this for the infinite dimensional case?